# Calculating and plotting very small values gives errors

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I want to plot the difference between $sin(x)$ and its Maclaurin series of order $200$ and more on $[0,1]$.

When I run the code

```
error[x_] = Sin[x] - Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 200}]];
N[error[1], 500]
```

I get an error message

> Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while 
> evaluating 
> -((1963410391502797893390796845628341196181950954203345943657372226021
> 7880597655701332158979418609723560351303854634053732931517193406757011
> 5<<94>>608012596588421747004213863754902836820901759185701726945750964
> 7034137503676042794159391336019551182168002237136382962149659462965975
> 315433)/(
> 2333307299895829892166755070805281249393893425109980068919356607231832
> 69219941817432042687577510243758632311283704035156880959405397229912<<
> 94>>483799533750218648640003720134850794852739739361450662906365978872
> 1780441485881349813724774400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 000))<<1>>Sin<<1>><<1>>].

also when I try to plot the difference I get another error message

```
Plot[error[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> (2.77086*10^-249 
> (-1))/4274883284060025564298013753389399649690343788366813724672000000
> 000000 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; 
> precision may be lost.

The question is, how to plot and calculate very small values such as $10^{-1000}$?

Comment: MMA informs you that you have numbers too small to be represented as normalized real number. A normalized real number is 1.xxxx times 2^exponent, where x and exponent are all binary digits. A nonnormalized number reads: 0.xxxx 2^exponent. This has lower pecision than 1.xxx 2^exponent.

Comment: You can eval each individually at high precision, subtract, and live with the cancellation error that loses you substantial precision. `In[56]:= sinser[x_] = Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 200}]];

In[58]:= N[Sin[1], 500] - N[sinser[1], 500]

Out[58]= \
6.30818921631005374655044903054825814974963992472620376751602664814354\
07711329570715726165870370939006583396742390256305715*10^-378` For plotting, I'd use high `WorkingPrecision` and a log scale, like so. `ListPlot[Table[Log[10, numdiff[x, 500]], {x, 0, 1, 1/100}]]`

Answer (score 7):

High-order polynomials with alternating signs are notoriously difficult to evaluate numerically. Such is the case for the sine function:

```
Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n + 1)/(2 n + 1)!, {n, 0, ∞}]
(*    Sin[x]    *)
```

But Mathematica contains a lot of special functions that are implemented with much more stable algorithms. For example, if we take this sum only to order $m$ (in your case, $m=200$):

```
approx[m_, x_] = Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n + 1)/(2 n + 1)!, {n, 0, m}]
(*    Sin[x] + (-1)^m x^(2 m + 3) HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {m + 2, m + 5/2}, -x^2/4]/(2 m + 3)!    *)
```

the second term in this formula, $\frac{(-1)^m x^{2 m+3}}{(2 m+3)!}{}_1F_2\left(1;m+2,m+\frac52;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$, is exactly the finite sum you're looking for:

```
error[m_, x_] = Sin[x] - approx[m, x]
(*    -(-1)^m x^(2 m + 3) HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {m + 2, m + 5/2}, -x^2/4]/(2 m + 3)!    *)
```

Try it out for $m=3$:

```
error[3, x] // Expand
(*    -x + x^3/6 - x^5/120 + x^7/5040 + Sin[x]    *)
```

Its evaluation is much more stable, though:

```
N[error[200, 1], 20]
(*    -2.4038518371210338825*10^-877    *)

ListLinePlot[Table[{x, N[Log[-error[200, x]], 20]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/20}]]
```

[image]

We can even write the ratio of a hypergeometric function and a factorial as a "regularized" hypergeometric:

```
error[m_, x_] = -(-1)^m Sqrt[π] (x/2)^(2m+3) HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1}, {m+2, m+5/2}, -x^2/4]
```

This makes it very simple to [look up its properties](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQRegularized/).